# Powershell filter output data from Get-WinEvent

Tags: windows, powershell, events, output

How I can Write-Output only:

- TimeCreated
- Account Name
- Account Domain
- Object type
- and object name.

Code:

```
Get-WinEvent -ComputerName DS1 -LogName Security -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4670 and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]] and EventData[Data[@Name='ObjectType']='File']]"  | fl
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
TimeCreated  : 2020-04-15 7:38:42 AM
        ProviderName : Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
        Id           : 4670
        Message      : Permissions on an object were changed.

                       Subject:
                           Security ID:        S-9-9-291-9999999999-8999992562-9999999661-999999
                           Account Name:        todd
                           Account Domain:        dmn
                           Logon ID:        0x55555555555555

                       Object:
                           Object Server:    Security
                           Object Type:    File
                           Object Name:    F:\Share\share1\photo.png
                           Handle ID:    0x70a2

                       Process:
                           Process ID:    0x5
                           Process Name:    

                       Permissions Change:
                           Original Security Descriptor:    
                           New Security Descriptor:    O:S-9-9-291-9999999999-8999992562-9999999661-999999:DU
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test if your filter actually works, bus assuming that is ok, you have two options here.

1. Try and parse out the data (especially the `Message` part) using a lot of awkward regexes
2. Get the data you need from the XML

I prefer the second option:

```
$filter = "*[System[EventID=4670 and TimeCreated[timediff(@SystemTime) <= 86400000]] and EventData[Data[@Name='ObjectType']='File']]"
$result = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName DS1 -LogName Security -FilterXPath $filter | ForEach-Object {
    # convert the event to XML and grab the Event node
    $eventXml = ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event
    $eventData = $eventXml.EventData.Data
    # output the properties you need
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        TimeCreated   = [DateTime]$eventXml.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
        AccountName   = ($eventData | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'SubjectUserName' }).'#text'
        AccountDomain = ($eventData | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'SubjectDomainName' }).'#text'
        ObjectType    = ($eventData | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'ObjectType' }).'#text'
        ObjectName    = ($eventData | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'ObjectName' }).'#text'
        Computer      = $eventXml.System.Computer
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\TheOutputFile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Your correction works perfectly, and I wanrt to know what is the Object Message variable, I would like to printed out with the filtred objects.

Comment: @Adil I'm not sure what you mean by `Object Message`. You can view the items returned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4670)

Comment: I want to get the value of this property:
Message      : Permissions on an object were changed.

Comment: @Adil Ah, well that's just the standard description for event 4670. Simply add that as hardcoded text in the object: `Message = 'Permissions on an object were changed.'`